# Parse file to a struct array in Matlab

Tags: parsing, matlab, struct

I have a file containing information as follows:

```
id   allele1 allele2
1    A A
2    T A
3    A A
.    ...
.    ...
.    ...
```

I would like to parse the file into a struct array containing three fields `(id, allele1, allele2)` where id are all the numbers from 1 up to n, allele1 is the first column of characters and allele2 is the second column.

I however have trouble figuring out how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, it would be best to show what you've tried. However, this should get you started.

```
fid = fopen('input.txt','r');

%header line
line = fgetl(fid);
header = regexpi(line,'\W+','split');

ID=1;

%read first line
line = fgetl(fid);

while ischar(line)

   l = regexpi(line,'\W+','split');

   for i=1:numel(l)
       data(ID).(header{i}) = l(i);
   end
    ID = ID+1;
    line = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
```

Resulting in:

```
>> data

data = 

1x4 struct array with fields:
    id
    allele1
    allele2

>> data(1)

ans = 

         id: {'1'}
    allele1: {'A'}
    allele2: {'A'}

>> data(2)

ans = 

         id: {'2'}
    allele1: {'T'}
    allele2: {'A'}
```